# Property file is not including while building jar

Tags: java, spring, maven

When I’m building a jar file, Maven in my local is not including the property file.(It is showing null pointer exception). I have tried to execute in my local, it is working fine. I'm experiencing null pointer while running in our environment. I have tried including my property files in `src/main/resources` and I have tried including my property file in the same package itself.

Comment: `I have tried to execute in my local` - you mean on your IDE or local spark-submit?

Comment: I meant local meant in my IDE (without building any jar). After Building the jar, It is showing null point exception.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: did you make sure the files are packed in the jar? `jar tf my.jar | grep foobar ... `

Comment: Yes, I have, but when I'm decompiling the jar file, it is not showing my properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the pom's file so you have 2 solutions:

Put all your resource files (different than java files) to `src/main/resources` which is recomended.

Add to your pom this resources tag:

```
<build>
    <resources>
          <resource>
             <directory>src/main/java</directory>
             <includes>                      
                 <include>**/*</include>
             </includes>
       </resource>
       <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
       </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: I did added resource in my pom file. And I have added my resource files in src/main/resources and also tried adding in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this issue, It was my pom file. Instead of include, I have added exclude. It was removing the property file. When I was building the jar.

Anyways, thanks for your help.